# Extra redundant new line needed to see the expected result when dealing with multiline input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read multiline text and print it which seems to be very easy job but interestingly I see odd behavior

```
while True:

    client_input = ''
    print("Please enter your queries:")         # User input we'll be adding to
    for line in sys.stdin:   # Iterator loops over readline() for file-like object
        if line == '\n' or line=='':     # Got a line that was just a newline
            break            # Break out of the input loop
        client_input += line   # Keep adding input to variable
    print('cccccccccccccccc')
    print(client_input)
```

So now enter this multiline text

```
    {
        "xxxx": [
            {
                "zzzz": {
                    "zz": "a",
                    "eee": "d"
                }
            },
            {
                "qqq": {
                    "q": "a",
                    "a": "d"
                }
            }
        ]}
```

so I expect when I enter a new line after pasting this text to see `cccccccccccccccc` printed however I need to click enter twice to see the expected behavior .
anyone can help what is that extra need for new line is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to click twice to break out of the loop because when you paste it you are still in the last copied line:

```
        ]}
```

which is neither empty nor `'\n'`.

So the first enter is to go down to a new line, and the second enter is the input of a new line which breaks out of the loop.

---

If you want to only press the enter once you can paste it with a new line, or you can check the number of brackets.

##### Example:

```
import sys

counter = 0
brackets = '()[]{}'
count = lambda chars: sum([line.count(ch) for ch in chars])
while True:
    client_input = ''
    print("Please enter your queries:")         # User input we'll be adding to
    for line in sys.stdin:   # Iterator loops over readline() for file-like object
        counter += count(brackets[::2]) - count(brackets[1::2])
        if counter == 0:     # Counter is 0 again
            break            # Break out of the input loop
        client_input += line   # Keep adding input to variable
    print('cccccccccccccccc')
    print(client_input)
```

##### Note:

This solution will allow `]` to close `{`.

If you don't have too many brackets you can also save the first brackets kind as the digits, the second as the tens...

###### Code example:

```
import sys

counter = 0
brackets = '()[]{}'
count = lambda chars: sum([line.count(ch) * (10**idx) for idx, ch in enumerate(chars)])
while True:
    client_input = ''
    print("Please enter your queries:")         # User input we'll be adding to
    for line in sys.stdin:   # Iterator loops over readline() for file-like object
        counter += count(brackets[::2]) - count(brackets[1::2])
        if counter == 0:     # Counter is 0 again
            break            # Break out of the input loop
        client_input += line   # Keep adding input to variable
    print('cccccccccccccccc')
    print(client_input)
```

But this technique would only work correctly if you have less than 10 brackets from each kind and in some other cases.

If you have more than 10 then the following input would also cause a braking out of the loop: `[[[[[[[[[[}`.

---

A better approach is to use other counting mechanism like counting the different brackets types in a list or a dict.

##### For example:

```
import sys

brackets = '()[]{}'
counter = [0] * (len(brackets) // 2) # counter for each type of bracket
count = lambda chars: [line.count(ch) for ch in chars] # creates a list that counts each type of brackets (in the order received)
while True:
    client_input = ''
    print("Please enter your queries:")         # User input we'll be adding to
    for line in sys.stdin:   # Iterator loops over readline() for file-like object
        counter = list(map(lambda x, y: x+y, counter, count(brackets[::2])))
        counter = list(map(lambda x, y: x-y, counter, count(brackets[1::2])))
        if all(item == 0 for item in counter):     # Counter is 0 again
            break            # Break out of the input loop
        client_input += line   # Keep adding input to variable
    print('cccccccccccccccc')
    print(client_input)
```

Comment: Thanks is there anyway to make it work with only one enter?

Answer (score 0):

The last line you enter is seen by the program as:

`]}\n`

which is neither empty or just `\n`. This is why you need to hit enter twice.

If you want your input to be accepted after only one enter, you have to detect whether the line ends with a `\n` or not. However, this will include all the lines of the input, defeating the purpose.

A workaround is to keep a track of the opening and closing brackets in the `client_input`. For any opening bracket type, increase a counter and for any closing bracket type, decrease the same counter. Now if you encounter a `\n` when the counter is at zero, then all the input was valid (number of opening brackets == number of closing brackets).

Following is a sample code.

```py
import sys

# gets the count of all opening brackets in a line
def get_open(line):
    return line.count("{") + line.count("[") + line.count("(")
    
# gets the count of all closing brackets in a line    
def get_close(line):
    return line.count("}") + line.count("]") + line.count(")")

while True:
    client_input = ''
    count = 0
    print("Please enter your queries:") 
    for line in sys.stdin:
        count += get_open(line) - get_close(line) # add opening and subtract closing
        if line == '' or (line[-1] == '\n' and count == 0):
            break
        client_input += line
    print('cccccccccccccccc')
    print(client_input)
```

NOTE: This assumes the brackets to function the same. A "{" can be closed by a "]" too, since we only keep a track of the counts of opening and closing brackets. If you want to validate the data properly, use a stack. Check out this problem on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/) if you want to ensure validity of brackets.